# Mysql4: SQL for selecting one or zero record

Tags: sql, mysql, database

Table layout:

```
CREATE TABLE t_order  (id INT, custId INT, order DATE)
```

I'm looking for a SQL command to select a maximum of one row per order (the customer who owns the order is identified by a field named custId).

I want to select *ONE* of the customer's orders (doesn't matter which one, say sorted by id) if there is no order date given for any of the rows.

I want to retrieve an empty Resultset for the customerId, if there is already a record with given order date.

Here is an example. Per customer there should be one order at most (one without a date given). Orders that have already a date value should not appear at all.

```
  +---------------------------------------------------------+
  |id    |    custId       |  date                          |
  +---------------------------------------------------------+
  | 1              10         NULL                          |
  | 2              11         2008-11-11                    |
  | 3              12         2008-10-23                    |
  | 4              11         NULL                          |
  | 5              13         NULL                          |
  | 6              13         NULL                          |
  +---------------------------------------------------------+
                           |
                           |
                           |      Result
                         \ |  /
                          \  /
  +---------------------------------------------------------+
  |id    |    custId       |  date                          |
  +---------------------------------------------------------+
  | 1              10         NULL                          |
  |                                                         |
  |                                                         |
  |                                                         |
  | 5              13         NULL                          |
  |                                                         |
  +---------------------------------------------------------+
                                powered be JavE
```

Edit: 
I've choosen glavić's answer as the correct one, because it provides
the correct result with slightly modified data:

```
  +---------------------------------------------------------+
  |id    |    custId       |  date                          |
  +---------------------------------------------------------+
  | 1              10         NULL                          |
  | 2              11         2008-11-11                    |
  | 3              12         2008-10-23                    |
  | 4              11         NULL                          |
  | 5              13         NULL                          |
  | 6              13         NULL                          |
  | 7              11         NULL                          |
  +---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Sfossen's answer will not work when customers appear more than twice because of its where clause constraint a.id != b.id.

Quassnoi's answer does not work for me, as I run server version 4.0.24 which yields the following error:
[alt text http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/8186/picture1vyj.png](http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/8186/picture1vyj.png)

Comment: What other columns are in this table? custID with a Null date would have no reason to exist?

Comment: Have you tested any of the answers to see if it works for you?

Comment: I tested. On given data all three work: @sfossen's, @glavic's and mine.

Comment: can you tell us what issues you are experiencing with any of the answers so we can help get this question closed.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Smells of denormalization to me.

Comment: You got me here, 4.0 didn't support subqueries yet :)

Comment: @erikkallen: Your're totally right. It smells a lot. But that's another story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT to1.*
FROM t_order AS to1
WHERE
    to1.date IS NULL AND 
    to1.custId NOT IN (
        SELECT to2.custId
        FROM t_order AS to2
        WHERE to2.date IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY to2.custId
    )
GROUP BY to1.custId
```

For MySQL 4:

```
SELECT to1.*
FROM t_order AS to1
LEFT JOIN t_order AS to2 ON
    to2.custId = to1.custId AND
    to2.date IS NOT NULL
WHERE
    to1.date IS NULL AND 
    to2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY to1.custId
```

Comment: I really don't know why I have earned -1 vote? Maybe because my code works in MySQL 5 and MySQL 4? very interesting...

Comment: I don't know either. maybe someone thinks he can do it in a simpler way. Well then, let's see your solution, Mister!

Comment: I know, someone didn't like my code styling, lol ;) Ah, all it really matters that you have your problem solved. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

For a specific customer it's:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_order
WHERE date IS NULL AND custId=? LIMIT 1
```

For all customers its:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM t_order a 
    LEFT JOIN t_order b ON a.custId=b.custID and a.id != b.id
WHERE a.date IS NULL AND b.date IS NULL
GROUP BY custId;
```

Comment: Wont work, both examples will return a customer even if the customer has a date in another row. The asker does not want this.

Answer (score 1):

This query will use one pass over index on `custId`.

For each distinct `custId` it will use one subquery over same index.

No `GROUP BY`, no `TEMPORARY` and no `FILESORT` — efficient, if your table is large.

```
SELECT VERSION()

--------
'4.1.22-standard'

CREATE INDEX ix_order_cust_id ON t_order(custId)

SELECT id, custId, order_date
FROM (
  SELECT o.*,
    CASE
      WHEN custId <> @c THEN
        (
        SELECT 1
        FROM   t_order oi
        WHERE  oi.custId = o.custId
          AND  order_date IS NOT NULL
        LIMIT 1
        )
    END AS n,
    @c <> custId AS f,
    @c := custId
  FROM
    (
    SELECT @c := -1
    ) r,
    t_order o
  ORDER BY custId
) oo
WHERE n IS NULL AND f

---------
1, 10, ''
5, 13, ''
```

Comment: very intersting, even though I don't grasp it :) 
I would be interested how this solution performs in comparison with the others.

Comment: No GROUP BY, no TEMPORARY, no FILESORT -- how do you think it may perform? ;)

Answer (score 0):

First filter out rows with dates, then filter out any row that has a similar row with a lower id.  This should work because the matching record with the least id is unique if id is unique.

```
select * from t_order o1
    where date is null
      and not exists (select * from t_order o2
                         where o2.date is null
                           and o1.custId = o2.custId
                           and o1.id > o2.id)
```

Comment: First, he needs it for MySQL 4, so query without subselects must be used. Second, this query doesn't work like he want's it to work, read the question again. Third, why use id in condition ?